# About electron and proton

Tags: electrons, nuclear-physics, protons, pions

Can electron stick ''glue''  with proton if they collide with each other? 
What will happen if electron collide with pion? Can it glue with it or not?

Comment: I believe the word you're looking for is "bind".

Comment: Why a pion? Anyway, you may find this relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_capture

Answer (score 1):

> Can electron stick ''glue'' with proton if they collide with each other?

Depending on the energy , electron proton scattering will either see the proton as a whole nucleon, for low energy, or as the three quarks that compose it.

The electron cannot "glue" with the quarks of the proton because of lepton number conservation, and the lack of any evidence for [leptoquark models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leptoquark).

If it has a low enough energy it can bind in the potential (electromagnetic interaction)and form a [hydrogen atom](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/hydcn.html).

> What will happen if electron collide with pion? Can it glue with it or not?

The pion is a bound state of a quark and antiquark. Lepton number is conserved and there is no evidence for leptoquarks, so it cannot "glue" with a pion. In addition one cannot have pions as targets, but they can exist in beams and interact with electrons by scattering them, and if the energy is high enough pair production of particle antiparticles might happen, and quark and gluon jets, with small probability since the interaction responsible is the electromagnetic one.

Comment: Can electron stick with proton at low energy without forming hydrogen atom

Comment: No, it will bounce off, or it will be trapped in an  energy level of hydrogen.  It might make a resonance since energy levels have been found above ionisation (http://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.432549 ) but not be trapped  since there is a lifetime.